# Why python super() not working without parameters in ABCMETA class?

Tags: python, super, metaclass, abc, six

I have a problem with understanding function super() behavior in abc.ABCMeta class in python3.6.

```py
class ParentClass():
    def test():
        return 1
​
@six.add_metaclass(ABCMeta)
class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def test(self):
        test_ = super().test
        test_ = 2
        return test_
​
a = ChildClass()
​
a.test()
```

Code failed with `'TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type'`.

When I used `super(ChildClass, self).test` it worked correctly! Printing from ChildClass test function:

`print(__class__)`

`print(type(__class__))`

`print(ChildClass)`

`print(type(ChildClass))`

I get next output:

`<class '__main__.ChildClass'>`

`<class 'type'>`

`<class '__main__.ChildClass'>`

`<class 'abc.ABCMeta'>`

I feel that the reason in object initialization but I can't undersand this information with my current skills in OOP and Python OOP.

Comment: Not an answer but it makes me wonder: It's a bit odd that you define an abstract base class that isn't actually a "base-class" but a derived class from a non-abstract base class. 

Comment: For simplicity of understanding my problem. In reality I have `@abstractmethod` in `ChildClass` and `ChildClassTwo(ChildClass)` which defines this method.

Comment: I meant why `ParentClass` isn't an abstract base class. Also it's not really relevant, I just wondered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0-argument `super` uses the class in which the call actually appeared, but after `@six.add_metaclass(ABCMeta)`, the class bound to the `ChildClass` name is a new class created by the decorator. 0-argument `super` is still using the original class.

If you're going to use 0-argument `super`, which only works on Python 3, just use Python 3 metaclass syntax instead of `six`.

Comment: Just if anyone wonders: The metaclass syntax in Python 3.x in this case would be: `class ChildClass(ParentClass, metaclass=ABCMeta): ...`